# How to make a variable global without the global keyword?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I have a variable called A, and two functions, here some code to follow all along:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
def bar():
    b = a + 2
    print b
foo()
bar()
```

This is a minimal basic example that explain my situations. Normally, In order to use `a` in the function `bar()`, either we mark `a` as `global` or we return it, or we can define `a` outside of the function (global scope). In my case I can't do any one of these.

Is there any other way to be able to access `a` in `bar`?

Comment: Return it from `foo`. There's not another way.

Comment: `globals()["a"] = 1`?  :-)

Comment: This is one of the ways where we can avoid both `global`s and `return`s. http://ideone.com/ZieCEa

Comment: Why do you want to use globals?  And even worse, why do you want to make it hard to tell you are using globals?

Comment: Sorry, but did you even read the question ? I'm looking for a way to use them with out global  .... I DON'T WANT TO USE gloabals .

Comment: "How to make a variable global without the global keyword?" does not convey the idea that you don't want to use globals.